# How do I display the file contents only when checkbox is checked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In the given code below, only when the "x" checkbox is checked, the "ChoosexFile" button should get enabled. Only when clicked upon the "ChoosexFile" button, the "file dialog box" must get opened. And the selected file contents must be displayed in the "Listbox" of the middle frame. The listbox of both middle frame & bottom frame must contain both "horizontal" & "vertical" scrollbar. And when clicked upon the "clear" button(top frame), the file contents being displayed in the "Listbox" of the middle frame must get cleared and the checkbox of it(either x or y) must get automatically unchecked. The same must get repeated for "y" checkbox(i.e the functionality must be same as "x"). And when clicked upon "reset" button of the middle frame, all the contents being displayed in the "listbox"(middle frame) must get cleared and also all the checkboxes must get unchecked automatically.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def forButton1():
    filename1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    with open(filename1) as f:
        for i in f:
            myList.insert(END, i)

    print(filename1)

def forButton2():
    filename1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    with open(filename1) as f:
        for i in f:
            myList.insert(END, i)

    print(filename1)

def forButton7():
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.title("Spatialization of DSSAT")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

topFrame = LabelFrame(root, text="Select input file")
topFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=8, pady=8, sticky=N+E+S+W)
topFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
topFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
topFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
topFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
topFrame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

middleFrame = LabelFrame(root, text="Input data")
middleFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=8, pady=8, sticky=N+E+S+W)
middleFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
middleFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=0)
middleFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
middleFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

bottomFrame = LabelFrame(root, text="Model Output")
bottomFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=8, pady=8, sticky=N+E+S+W)
bottomFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
bottomFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

MyVar1 = IntVar()
MyVar2 = IntVar()

MyCheckbutton1 = Checkbutton(topFrame, text="x", variable=MyVar1)
MyCheckbutton1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
Button1 = Button(topFrame, text="Choose xFile", command=forButton1)
Button1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)
Button3 = Button(topFrame, text="Clear")
Button3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=4, pady=4)

MyCheckbutton2 = Checkbutton(topFrame, text="y", variable=MyVar2)
MyCheckbutton2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)
Button2 = Button(topFrame, text="Choose yFile", command=forButton2)
Button2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)
Button4 = Button(topFrame, text="Clear")
Button4.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=4, pady=4)

innerMiddleFrame = Frame(middleFrame)
innerMiddleFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=4, pady=4)
innerMiddleFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
innerMiddleFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(innerMiddleFrame)
myList = Listbox(innerMiddleFrame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
myList.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+E+S+W)
scrollbar.config(command=myList.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+E+S+W)

Button5 = Button(middleFrame, text="Reset")
Button5.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

Button6 = Button(middleFrame, text="Submit")
Button6.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=4, pady=4)

innerBottomFrame = Frame(bottomFrame)
innerBottomFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=4, pady=4)
innerBottomFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
innerBottomFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(innerBottomFrame)
myList = Listbox(innerBottomFrame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
myList.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+E+S+W)
scrollbar.config(command=myList.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+E+S+W)

Button7 = Button(bottomFrame, text="Exit", command=forButton7)
Button7.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=4, pady=4)

root.geometry("400x590")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: To get the state of your checkboxes use `MyVar1.get()` and `MyVar2.get()`. It is 0 for unchecked and 1 for checked. But you need to add some logic to _collect_ these states. Right now your code is executed once and you can't collect states if they've changed. Consider rewriting your code into functions and add logic that would _listen_ to the changes.

Comment: Where to add ```MyVar1.get()```   ```MyVar2.get()``` in the code?

Comment: And I want the "Choosexfile" button to get enabled only when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I got it about the checkbox activation.

Comment: May I please know how to display the file contents in the listbox of the second frame?

Answer (score 0):

Start out your buttons with a disabled state, and make a function to toggle their state by clicking the checkboxes.

```
Button1 = Button(topFrame, text="Choose xFile", command=forButton1, state="disabled")
Button2 = Button(topFrame, text="Choose yFile", command=forButton2, state="disabled")

...

def check_state(widget):
    if widget["state"] == "normal":
        widget["state"] = "disabled"
    else:
        widget["state"] = "normal"

MyCheckbutton1.config(command=lambda: check_state(Button1))
MyCheckbutton2.config(command=lambda: check_state(Button2))
```

Comment: May I please know how to display the file contents in the listbox of the second frame?

Comment: i.e in the middle frame. In my code, it is being displayed in the bottom frame. I dont want it to be displayed in the bottom frame of the listbox. I want the file contents which is selected to be displayed in the middle frame of the list box.

Comment: And what's preventing you from doing so? You defined both listbox as `MyList` and obviously it will always display in the same middle frame.

Comment: When I run the code, it is being displayed in the listbox of the bottom frame. But I want it to be displayed in the listbox of the middle frame.

Comment: I already told you that you defined both listbox in bottom and middle frame with the same variable name.

Comment: Yeah I got it. May I know how to clear the contents being displayed in the listbox of the middle frame when the "clear" button of the "x" or "y" button is being clicked?

Comment: Also when the clear button(of x or y button) is clicked, the checkbutton should automatically get unchecked.

Comment: I'm sure you can find the answers by searching your questions one at a time.